# How to call a javascript function in a node template?

Tags: nodes, javascript

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to call a javascript function I have in a node template.

The flow I am trying to achieve is a user clicks a link (its a link which activates the colorbox module).  This then loads a node template with a video and my custom javascript function I want to call.  Then when the user closes the colorbox a callback is made which should then call my custom function.

I have a general javascript file loaded into my omega theme which listens for the colorbox link and on the close callback I want it to call the function defined in the called node.

The javascript in my functions file is:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.l_d_links = 
{   
    attach: function (context, settings) 
    {
        $('.colorbox-load').colorbox({
            onCleanup:function(){ dbUpdate(); }
        });
    }
} 
})(jQuery);
```

And javascript code in my node is:

```
function dbUpdate() { console.log("start $.post"); }
```

Just to add the reasoning behind putting the function in the node template is because I need access to some php variables on node load.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: Just got home and fired up my home PC to try and troubleshoot, however the code is working now o.O

Comment: could you please post your answer and check it as the solution. It will help our community :)